# Is it possible to update a document, in the callback function after saving a new document in another collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm saving the newPost document, into the posts collection, and in the then() function, i'd like to update other documents, but in the tags collection. However, for some reason, this change in the tags collection doesn't occur, and res.json(post) doesn't return the new post as it should.

I'm using postman for making requests to the server.

When I take out the code snippet where I make changes to the tags collection, res.json(post) works, and the post created is returned in json format in Postman, however, when placed back, nothing seems to work. The post however, is pushed to the database, and is view-able in the collection.

```
const newPost = new Post({
    authorId: user._id,
    text: req.body.text,
    title: req.body.title,
    tags: req.body.tags.split(", ")
});

newPost.save()
.then(post => {
// here, I'd like to do the following commented section or something
//similar:
// Tag.findAndModify({
//     query: {name: {$all: [post.tags]}},
//     update: {
//         $push: {posts: post._id},
//         $set: {lastActive: new Date()}
//     }
// });
 res.json({post});
}).catch(err=>res.json(err));
```

without the section commented, post is successfully added to database, res.json(post) returns the post in Postman; with the section uncommented, post is successfully added to database, but tags collection modification doesn't occur, and res.json(post) is empty in postman

Comment: `.findAndModify()` is likely an async operation, you'll need `await` or `.then()` to wait for it to complete. Just like what you did with `.save().then()`

Answer (score 1):

you need to return res.json after saving since it's an async operation.

```
    const newPost = new Post({
        authorId: user._id,
        text: req.body.text,
        title: req.body.title,
        tags: req.body.tags.split(", ")
    });

    newPost.save()
    .then(post => {
    // here, I'd like to do the following commented section or something
    //similar:
     Tag.findAndModify({
         query: {name: {$all: [post.tags]}},
         update: {
             $push: {posts: post._id},
             $set: {lastActive: new Date()}
         }
     }).exec((err,tags)=>{
        if(err) //return error
        res.json({post,tags});
     });

    }).catch(err=>res.json(err));
```